# Searching,sorting on gird-view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I try this example for search and sort but in this example they use table and I am using `gridview`

[datatable example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glPsD.png)

I try this

```
public DataTable info(string id)
{
    try
    {
        Entities2 wr = new Entities2();
        List<spvechile_Result> sv = wr.spvechile(id).ToList();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(int)); 
        foreach (var c in sv)
        {
        dt.Rows.Add(c.Name);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

so how is this this possible to use this example with gridview

**latest update**

i modify this file .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
```

and remove padding-right:30px 
so after i this this is the result
this is updated html

```
    <div class="panel" id="paneldiv">           
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="firstgrid">
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
        CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" Width="100%" CellPadding="0"
        Font-Names="Verdana" BackColor ="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" 
        BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="9pt">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>          
        </div>
```

[image]

in the last column there is long text and beacuse of this formatting not correct and grid-view  height become so long  how to manage this

Comment: why down 2 on this question :O

Comment: Put your latest grid view html content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GridView1").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [3] }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Add css class in gridview `CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered"` and set `Width="100%" CellPadding="0"`

For your refrence:[jquery bootstrap datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

**UPDATE:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
        CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" Width="100%" CellPadding="0"
        Font-Names="Verdana" BackColor ="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" 
        BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="9pt">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I have added only this line `CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" Width="100%" CellPadding="0"` in your current `gridview` HTML

Comment: this is for table or gridview? @Krunal Mevada

Comment: i also add like this but always gridview display with wrong formatting

Comment: Put your latest gridview HTML

Comment: You need to wrap text of last column.